# Get all files in a directory recursively from a particular git commit

Tags: git, directory, subdirectory, git-checkout

My folder structure looked like this:

```
root -> Model -> Simulation -> (many sub directories and files in it)
```

1. I committed it and the sha is `022f5fb`.
2. Later I deleted the `Simulation` folder. And it was committed.
3. And then many commits were committed all which involved addition of new files and removal of certain other etc etc.

Now I need to get the `Simulation` folder and all the files in it recursively (at the time of commit `022f5fb`) to the current working directory.

I know I have to do something with `git checkout 022f5fb` or something but that will checkout the whole working directory. I only need `Simulation` folder and its contents.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git checkout 022f5fb -- path/to/Simulation
```

should do it. Also see [the `git checkout` main page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).